# How to manipulate properties of Livedata list

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-mvvm

Say like `LiveData<List<Item>` is received from remote and few of the `Item`'s properties are calculated in the device based on some conditions. 
What would be the best practices to do so. Please suggest.

Say e.g., Item class as below:

```
class Item{
   int id
   String name
   float location
   float distance 
}
```

in which the `id`, `name` and `location` of each `Item` are received from remote but the `distance` to be calculated from location locally. How to calculate the `distance` and return a LiveData which can be supplied back to the View?

Appreciate your time and input.

Answer (score 1):

You cant manipulate LiveData, it is an immutable data type. If you want to work with mutable live data you must use the MutableLiveData.

This document told everything about it. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata

Comment: True. Was in search of a similar sample to get more insight into it. Thanks anyway, appreciated :)